# How do I dynamically invoke or call a class in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, dynamic, invoke

Assuming I can construct a string that matches an existing class, how do I invoke it?

For example, I have several classes:

- MyClass1
- MyClass2
- MyClass3

And I want to dynamically invoke each of them by constructing a string that matches their names. If they all had the method "methods", how do I do something like this?:

```
(1..3).each do |n|
  ("MyClass"+n).methods
end
```

Comment: Are you sure anonymous classes in an array wouldn't fit? As soon as you start using the namespace by iteration, you should rethink your code.

Comment: Hi Tass, can you expand on "anonymous classes in an array"? I'm fairly positive this isn't the best way to solve a problem I'm currently working on, but I thought I should know how to do something like this anyway.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`constantize` fits the bill. You can read more about it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize). In your case it would be something like:

```
(1..3).each do |n|
  "MyClass#{n}".constantize.methods
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Following up on zsquare's answer, I ended up with two answers!
    
    klass = Object.const_get "MyClassName"

-or-

    klass = "MyClassName".constantize

Both return the class for whatever brand of fun you're interested in.

While looking around, I also found the Inflector class to be handy for dynamically building class names.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize

Answer (score -3):

you can also do -

```
(1..3).each {|n| eval "MyClass#{n}.methods"}
```

Comment: Downvote for `eval`. You shouldnt use something like `eval` unless you are sure you have to, and are sure there is NO other way to do it. And then, if you're sure you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: if you need to do it in ruby i.e. no rails, what other way would you invoke it?

Comment: `classname = 'Integer';
Kernel.const_get(classname).methods`